# Is it possible to replace favicon with @font-face?

Tags: html, css, font-face, favicon

I'm planning to create a cross-browser web site that does not use images(.jpg, .png, .svg, etc.) for modern browsers. Is it possible to replace favicon.ico with a @font-face?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The favicon is an image resource, not text, so it cannot be replaced with an icon font using `@font-face`.

If you absolutely do not want to use an image file, you can always create the favicon in an image editor, then serialize the file into a [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/data_URIs):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/x-icon;base64,...">
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to use an image.
Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You have to definitely use an image. But if you need a quick favicon made of some text and a background try http://antifavicon.com/

Answer (score 0):

**The answer is NO**

Also it's ***not*** necessary to provide <Link> tag for your favicon.

Providing base64 data is much heavier. Instead, simply copy favicon.ico file to your webroot (public_html), server will automatically send this file as a favicon *faster than any method*.